# How can we achieve forcing a mandatory where clause on a particular field in the plural queries generated by TypeGraphQL?

Tags: typegraphql

For example in below 'users' query, I always want where clause on tenantId field. If client is calling users query without where clause with tenantId field, error should be thrown.
query MyQuery {
users(where: {tenantId: {equals: "123"}}) {
id
name
tenantId
}
}

I am new to TypeGraphQL. Just want to know, can it be done without writing custom resolver or do we need to write any custom resolver to achieve it. If writing custom resolver is the case then what will be the pattern to write it? Thanks a lot for any suggestion.